# Disable auto_prepend in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using auto_prepend in htaccess on my website and I don't want it to be used in subfolder.

For example, in the root folder, the .htaccess have this line

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "path/to/file.php"
```

In the admin folder, root/admin, have

```
RewriteRule . front-controller.php [L]
```

and here I have some problem because of some class or function loaded twice...

Then how to avoid load auto_prepend in the /admin folder?

Answer (score 2):

To disable `auto_prepend` in specific folder, just paste this code in the `.htaccess` file of that specific folder

```
php_value auto_prepend_file none
```

For your case, create a `.htaccess` file under folder `root/admin` and paste the above code.